# Xamarin UISwipeGestureRecognizer Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uigesturerecognizer, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms I want to be able to swipe left and right to navigate a list of pictures. At the moment I just want to be able to fire an event each time a swipe is detected.

child class to be used in the renderer:

```
public class LRMasterDetailPage : ContentView
{
}
```

I have a ContentPage that uses the LRM class like this:

```
    public class ImagePage : ContentPage 
    {

    public ImagePage(Photo photo)
        {
            _image = new WebImage
                {
                    Url = photo.Url,
                    Placeholder = "placeHolder2.png"
                };

            var imageView = new LRMasterDetailPage {
                Content = _image
            };

            this.Content = imageView;
           }
      }
```

This is my Renderer:

```
    [assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(LRMasterDetailPage), typeof(LRMDPRenderer))]
namespace Project.iOS
{
    public class LRMDPRenderer : ViewRenderer<LRMasterDetailPage,UIView>
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipe;

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<LRMasterDetailPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            // Do someting else, init for example
            swipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
            this.AddGestureRecognizer (swipe);

            if (swipe.Direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left) 
            {
                UpdateLeft ();
            }

            if (swipe.Direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right) 
            {
                UpdateRight ();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
                return;
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);

        }

        private void UpdateLeft(){
            // Insert view of DetailLeft element into subview
            // Add button to open Detail to parent navbar, if not yet there
            // Add gesture recognizer for left swipe
            Console.WriteLine ("Left swipe");

        }
        private void UpdateRight(){
            // same as for left, but flipped
            Console.WriteLine ("Right swipe");

        }
    }
}
```

When the ContentPage is display the swipe right event is activated, but nothing happens when I try to swipe on top of the image. I am guessing my logic on the renderer is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much pain and searching around the web I found the solution.

What you need to do is simple: in the renderer declare and add the gesture. Make sure you create a swipe gesture for right and left each by declaring their direction. from there use a lambda to call the function you want activated for the specific swipe:

Placeholder class for the Swipe Gestures.

```
public class LRMasterDetailPage : ContentView
    {

    }
```

Image Page that holds one image at the time

```
public class ImagePage : ContentPage
{

    //view holding the image
    LRMasterDetailPage imageView;

    //collection of images using the photo.Url
    ObservableCollection<Image> images;

    //current image index
    int index = 0;

public ImagePage(){

       images = new ObservableCollection<Image> ();
       imageView = new LRMasterDetailPage {
            Content = this.images [index]
        };

        this.Content = imageView;
}

 //Subscribe to the swipeLeft and swipeRight message
  protected override void OnAppearing ()
    {
        base.OnAppearing ();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe <string> (this,"LeftSwipe", (sender) => {

            //Do something
            if(index < images.Count-1){
                index++;
            }

            imageView.Content = this.images[index];


        });
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe <string> (this, "RightSwipe", (sender) => {

            //Do something
            if(index > 0){
                index--;
            }

            imageView.Content = this.images[index];


        });
   }

     protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        //this._image = null;

        images = null;

        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<string>(this,"LeftSwipe");
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<string>(this, "RightSwipe");
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<string>(this, "LongPress");

        //GC.Collect();
    }

}
```

Renderer for LRMasterDetailPage

```
    [assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(LRMasterDetailPage), typeof(LRMDPRenderer))]
namespace Manager.iOS
{
    public class LRMDPRenderer : ViewRenderer<LRMasterDetailPage,UIView>
    {

        UILongPressGestureRecognizer longPressGestureRecognizer;
        UIPinchGestureRecognizer pinchGestureRecognizer;
        //UIPanGestureRecognizer panGestureRecognizer;
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeRightGestureRecognizer;
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeLeftGestureRecognizer;
        UIRotationGestureRecognizer rotationGestureRecognizer;

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<LRMasterDetailPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            longPressGestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer (() => Console.WriteLine ("Long Press"));
            pinchGestureRecognizer = new UIPinchGestureRecognizer (() => Console.WriteLine ("Pinch"));
            //panGestureRecognizer = new UIPanGestureRecognizer (() => Console.WriteLine ("Pan"));

            swipeRightGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer ( () => UpdateRight()){Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right};
            swipeLeftGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer ( () => UpdateLeft()){Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left};
            rotationGestureRecognizer = new UIRotationGestureRecognizer (() => Console.WriteLine ("Rotation"));

            if (e.NewElement == null) {
                if (longPressGestureRecognizer != null) {
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer (longPressGestureRecognizer);
                }
                if (pinchGestureRecognizer != null) {
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer (pinchGestureRecognizer);
                }

                /*
                if (panGestureRecognizer != null) {
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer (panGestureRecognizer);
                }
                */

                if (swipeRightGestureRecognizer != null) {
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer (swipeRightGestureRecognizer);
                }
                if (swipeLeftGestureRecognizer != null) {
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer (swipeLeftGestureRecognizer);
                }

                if (rotationGestureRecognizer != null) {
                    this.RemoveGestureRecognizer (rotationGestureRecognizer);
                }
            }

            if (e.OldElement == null) {
                this.AddGestureRecognizer (longPressGestureRecognizer);
                this.AddGestureRecognizer (pinchGestureRecognizer);
                //this.AddGestureRecognizer (panGestureRecognizer);
                this.AddGestureRecognizer (swipeRightGestureRecognizer);
                this.AddGestureRecognizer (swipeLeftGestureRecognizer);
                this.AddGestureRecognizer (rotationGestureRecognizer);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateLeft(){
            MessagingCenter.Send ("Swiped to the left", "LeftSwipe");

        }
        private void UpdateRight(){
            // same as for left, but flipped
            MessagingCenter.Send ("Swiped to the Right", "RightSwipe");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever get finish wiring up the UpdateLeft and UpdateRight functions? Would be extremely helpful to see how you updated the view from here:) @ScarletMerlin

Comment: I will edit the answer to show the full code in a few minutes. All I do is send a message saying update right / left.

Comment: @AnthonyRyan I have edited the answer to include all the code you would need to swipe images left and right and any other gesture you can think of. enjoy. vote and like if it did help you.